# Proving that $\liminf (x_n)+\liminf (y_n)\le \liminf (x_n+y_n)$

Tags: real-analysis

I know that $\limsup (x_n)+\limsup (y_n)\ge \limsup (x_n+y_n)$, but I'm not sure how to show that $\liminf (x_n)+\liminf (y_n)\le \liminf (x_n+y_n)$. Please help me.

Comment: Do you know how to prove that $\limsup(x_n+y_n) \le \limsup(x_n) + \limsup(y_n)$?

Comment: Hint: $\limsup (-x_n) = - \liminf x_n$

Comment: Yes I know how it prove.....but please independent proof

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Fix $n$ for the moment and let $l \ge n$. Since $\inf_{ k \ge n} x_k \le x_l$ and $\inf_{ k \ge n} y_k \le y_l$, we see that
$\inf_{ k \ge n} x_k + \inf_{ k \ge n} y_k \le x_l + y_l$. Hence
$\inf_{ k \ge n} x_k + \inf_{ k \ge n} y_k \le \inf_{ k \ge n} ( x_k + y_k)$.

Since these are non decreasing sequences, we have
$\inf_{ k \ge n} x_k + \inf_{ k \ge n} y_k \le \liminf_{ k } ( x_k + y_k)$ and
hence $\liminf_{ k } x_k + \liminf_{ k } y_k \le \liminf_{ k } ( x_k + y_k)$.

Answer (score 4):

Start with the inequality for $\limsup$ that you know, and use the hint of RRL.
\begin{align}
\limsup (-x_n) + \limsup (-y_n) &\ge \limsup (-x_n-y_n)\\
-\liminf x_n - \liminf y_n &\ge -\liminf (x_n+y_n)\\
\liminf x_n + \liminf y_n &\le \liminf (x_n+y_n)
\end{align}

Comment: Please independent proof

Answer (score 3):

Recall that $\liminf x_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} \inf_{k \geqslant n} x_k.$

Note that for all $k \geqslant n$

$$x_k \geqslant \inf_{j \geqslant n} x_j,\\ y_k \geqslant \inf_{j \geqslant n} y_j$$

Thus,

$$x_k + y_k \geqslant \inf_{j \geqslant n} x_j + \inf_{j \geqslant n} y_j \\ \implies  \inf_{k \geqslant n} (x_k + y_k) \geqslant \inf_{j \geqslant n} x_j + \inf_{j \geqslant n} y_j.$$

Now finish by taking the limit of both sides as $ n \to \infty.$